# Can't cope with Dialog and Gridgeometry manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrongly.
I want this [image: this]

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import Pmw

master = Tk()

class GetPassword(Pmw.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        self.title('Enter New Password')
        Label(master, text='Old Password:').grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text='New Password:').grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text='Enter New Password Again:').grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        self.oldpw = Entry(master, width = 16, show='*')
        self.newpw1 = Entry(master, width = 16, show='*')
        self.newpw2 = Entry(master, width = 16, show='*')

        self.oldpw.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.newpw1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.newpw2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

a = GetPassword()
a.body(master)
master.mainloop()
```

The result looks likt this:

[image]

My problems:

1. The title is Tk instead of Enter New Password.
2. I somehow manage to split the frame in two: 1. Entry fields. 2. Buttons.
3. I'm getting only one button (Cancel button is lost somewhere).

I would be thankful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. The title is Tk instead of Enter New Password.

You need to set title for `master`. The code in the question put widgets in the `master` (main window).

```
master = Tk()
master.title('Enter New Password')
```

This may not be needed, if you solve the second problem.

### 2. I somehow manage to split the frame in two: ...

In the dialog `body` method, you're putting widget into the master. Use `Pmw.Dialog.interior()` to put widgets into dialog:

```
def body(self, master):
    self.title('Enter New Password')
    Label(self.interior(), text='Old Password:').grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    Label(self.interior(), text='New Password:').grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Label(self.interior(), text='Enter New Password Again:').grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    self.oldpw = Entry(self.interior(), width = 16, show='*')
    self.newpw1 = Entry(self.interior(), width = 16, show='*')
    self.newpw2 = Entry(self.interior(), width = 16, show='*')

    self.oldpw.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    self.newpw1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    self.newpw2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

### 3. I'm getting only one button (Cancel button is lost somewhere).

Use [`buttons` option](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/Dialog.html#option.buttons) to list names of buttons:

```
a = GetPassword(buttons=('OK', 'Cancel'))
```

[image]

Comment: Working. Thank you very much. But I can't catch the idea of interior(). self.interior() is the parent here. Could you clarify what self.interior() means here?

Comment: @user3475946, [`interior`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/Dialog.html#method.interior) returns child site for the dialog  which can be used to create custom widgets within it.  Please see [`Pmw.Dialog` documentation](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/Dialog.html) for more details.